# Please enter Username for - ServiceAccount deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I get `Please enter Username` when I try to deploy with a ServiceAccount, even I have set ClusterRole bindings - do you know why?

kubectl:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Role & binding:

```
kubectl create clusterrole tutorial-role \
               --verb=get,list,watch,create,update,patch,delete \
               --resource=deployments


kubectl create clusterrolebinding tutorial-binding \
             --clusterrole=tutorial-role \
             --serviceaccount=default:tutorial-service
```

Create config user:

```
TOKEN=$(kubectl describe secrets "$(kubectl describe serviceaccount tutorial-service | grep -i Tokens | awk '{print $2}')" | grep token: | awk '{print $2}')
kubectl config set-credentials tutorialuser --token=$TOKEN
kubectl config set-context sausercontext --cluster=<my-cluster> --user=tutorialuser
kubectl config use-context sausercontext --namespace=default
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: leeroy-web
  labels:
    app: leeroy-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: leeroy-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: leeroy-web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: leeroy-web
          image: gcr.io/appsyouwear/leeroy-web
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

Info:

```
kubernetes % kubectl -v=8 apply -f deployment.yaml   
I0111 13:57:05.950317   63261 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /Users/username/.kube/config
Please enter Username:
```

Comment: can you run kubectl -v=8 apply -f deployment.yaml and see the verbose logs. Also what is the error in kube Api Server logs?

Comment: Can you provide the users section of kubeconfig file without sensitive data?

Comment: Then I get: loader.go:35... See updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Kubeconfig file is munged.Either you don't have an user in the contexts section or you don't have an user in the users section.
contexts and users section of your kubeconfig should look like below.

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: tutorialuser
  name: sausercontext


users:
- name: tutorialuser
  user: 
    token: <removed>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using kops then you can fix this by entering below command

```
kops export kubecfg --admin
```

or you can try this

```
kops update cluster ${NAME} --yes --state ${KOPS_STATE_STORE} --admin
```

or by exporting KOPS_STATE_STORE

```
export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://test-new-store
```

if you have not created s3 bucket then follow the below commands to create

```
aws s3 mb s3://test-new-store --region ap-south-1

aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket test-new-store --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled

export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://test-new-store
```